# restrict new account creation in Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, user-accounts, administrator, user, user-groups

My son needs to be an administrator on his Windows 10 computer in order to use some applications.  However, he keeps creating new accounts to bypass Norton's family protection and other local settings I created using scheduled tasks.

Is there anything else that I needs to do besides removing NT AUTORITY/INTERACTIVE from users group?

Comment: If you don't mind me asking, why does he *"need"* admin privileges on his Windows 10 computer?  What does he do that regularly requires that level of access?

Comment: Sounds like you should use human behavior solutions until your son stops making accounts .

Answer (score 1):

Question possibly to be migrated to a parenting forum.

Unplug the PSU from the wall, and the computer. Take it with you. When he "needs" it, he asks nicely and you sit and watch. 
If you have tenacity, he will get bored with this game before you and ask what he can do so you'll just leave him alone.

Sand boxing doesn't block content, or account creation.

Windows has implemented some kind of account heirachy but configuring it is likely going to be more of a headache for you than it is worth (and he will probably circumvent it anyway.) 
He shouldn't need admin rights for anything, "power user" should do. Specific access can be configured through gpedit.msc  and lusrmgr.msc. You will need to go through those to suit your situation.

If you don't require pornography, your best bet would be to block it at the router level (if your firmware supports it, or alternatively route all his traffic through a filternig DNS). You can also filter his network adapters by MAC address for time-restrictions. And as long as you set a **decent password** on the router he can't get around it, short of buying his own or using the neighbour's wifi.

Comment: This doesn't really answer the author's question